# Deploying LB4 appplication on Apache server

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I have tried deploying my Loopback 4 application on Apache running on a CentOS 7 server. I followed the instructions given [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/deploying-with-pm2-and-nginx.html)  for Nginx but the proxy pass through is not working on Apache. Is there any documentation on how to deploy a LB4 application on Apache?

Comment: For future cross-referencing, this has been posted elsewhere: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6782

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a complete answer as there was [no response](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6782) on the equivilent GitHub issue to better understand the user requirements.

The [official Apache 2 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) This should be a good starting point to mapping NGINX's configuration to Apache 2.